# Multi-Threaded Program Not Returning to Main Thread Immediately

Tags: python, windows, multithreading

**Challenge**

I have a program I wrote that uses two threads. One thread changes the color of the text and the background of the command prompt. The other thread displays a help menu or loops through a list of 1000 numbers. The problem is I want the program to return to the prompt and wait for new instructions instead of cycling through the color spectrum. What I would like is for the program to cycle through the color spectrum and also wait for the end-user to type something else at the command prompt. Is this not possible? This program will unfortunately only work on the Windows operating-system (OS).

Additionally, I cannot even Control-C out of the program if I want to because the thread I create will not listen for input apparently. Strange.

**The Code**

```
import os
import getopt
import time
import sys
import threading


def whiteRabbit():
    """Change the color of the command prompt while the program is executing."""

    for i in range(60):
        os.system('color %d' % i)
        time.sleep(1)

def goGoGo():
    for i in range(1000):
        print("Hey we have another number, %d " % i)

def howTo():
    print("Here are the options for this program")
    print ("%s -h (help menu. What you are reading now.)" % sys.argv[0])
    print("%s -g (goGoGo() mode. This prints a list of numbers to the console. Wow. :0" % sys.argv[0])
    print("%s --whiteRabbit (This changes the color of the console. Windows only. Sorry cool Unix people." % sys.argv[0])



if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:
        opts, args = getopt.gnu_getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'hg', ['whiteRabbit'])

        for opt, arg in opts:

            if opt in ('-h'):
                howTo()
            elif opt in ('-g'):
                goGoGo()
            elif opt in ('--whiteRabbit'):
                wr = threading.Thread(target=whiteRabbit)
                wr.start()

    except getopt.GetoptError as crap:
        howTo()
```

Comment: What options are you using to run the program?

Comment: -h --whiteRabbit or -g --whiteRabbit . Either of those options.

Comment: I think you need to make the thread a daemon: i.e.: `wr.daemon - True` _before_ calling `wr.start()`.

Comment: If I do that, `wr.daemon = True`, then the console does not change colors at all. Strange. This small code change makes the program behave as usual without any color changes.